# How to use Foreach Knockout on an element that contains Html.Partial

Tags: knockout.js

We are using knockout.js in mvc5.
The view contains 3 main DIVs, each one of them contains a separate partialView, that is loaded by the Html.Partial function on the server side

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-bind="css:{enabled:MyArray()[0].enable}">
        <label data-bind="text:MyArray()[0].title"></label>
        @Html.Partial(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Areas/SelectionBar/Views/SelectionBar/SelectDivision.cshtml"))
    </div>

    <div data-bind="css:{enabled:MyArray()[1].enable}">
        <label data-bind="text:MyArray()[1].title"></label>
        @Html.Partial(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Areas/SelectionBar/Views/SelectionBar/SelectSM.cshtml"))
    </div>

    <div data-bind="css:{enabled:MyArray()[2].enable}">
        <label data-bind="text:MyArray()[2].title"></label>
        @Html.Partial(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Areas/SelectionBar/Views/SelectionBar/SelectSM.cshtml"))
    </div>
</div>
```

The Viewmodel looks like this:

```
function getArray(){
var myObj1 = { "name": "menu1", "title": "Select SM",  "enable": true };
var myObj2 = { "name": "menu2", "title": "Select Division", "enable": true };
var myObj3 = { "name": "menu3", "title": "Search", "enable": false };
return [myObj1, myObj2, myObj3];
}
function SelectBarViweModel(){
var self = this;
self.MyArray = ko.observableArray(getArray());
self.IsSingleMode = ko.observable(true);
}
```

Since a lot of the code repeats itself, we would have liked to use Knockout's Foreach on MyArray. That way we would only have to write the Div once, and we wouldn't have to specify the index of the array (MyArray()[0] or  MyArray()[1](
But we ran into a problem because of the @Html.Partial that appears in each of the Divs, and is loaded on the server side.
How can we write reusable code using the Foreach, while supporting the render of @Html.Partial in each of the elements?

Thank you!

Comment: Personally, I think you need to make a decision around where you want the data to be rendered, the Client or Server.  Trying to get the client and the server to be aware of each other is going to require a lot of code that will be very difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do it all server-side by defining your menu structure in a `@{ }` block and looping through it via `@foreach (var menu in yourMenus) { ... }`. I'm no expert on the server-side, c#/razor details, but it's definitely a good option. Some examples can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c#objects-and-collections).

If you want to render *client-side*, but still want to use partials for re-usable parts of your views, I'd recommend using *templates*.

You'd define your templates somewhere in your shared layout like so:

```
<script type="text/html" id="t-selectSM">
  <div data-bind="css:{ enabled: enabled }">
    <label data-bind="text: title"></label>
    @Html.Partial(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Areas/SelectionBar/Views/SelectionBar/SelectDivision.cshtml"))
  </div>
<script>

<script type="text/html" id="t-selectDivision">
  <div data-bind="css:{ enabled: enabled }">
    <label data-bind="text: title"></label>
    @Html.Partial(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Areas/SelectionBar/Views/SelectionBar/SelectSM.cshtml"))
  </div>
<script>
```

Now, in your viewmodel, you can add references to these templates and use them to render your views:

```js
var MenuVM = function() {
  this.getTemplate = function(menu) {
    return menu.template;
  };

  this.menus = [
    { 
      name: "menu1", 
      title: "My Menu Title", 
      template: "t-selectDivsion", 
      enabled: true 
    }, {
      name: "menu2", 
      title: "Another Menu Title", 
      template: "t-selectSM", 
      enabled: false  
    }
  ];
};
```

With HTML:

```html
<div data-bind='template: { 
                  name: getTemplate,
                  foreach: menus 
                }'></div>
```

Comment: Your idea (to do it all server-side) helped us a lot! 

We've implemented it successfully
Thank you!